# Get last index of number

Tags: c#, arrays, list, indexing, int

Very simple question:

I am wondering how to get the last index of "1" in an array?

e.g. {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0} = 13.

Currently I use this method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < val.Count; i++)
{
     if (val[i] == 1)
     {
          value = i + 1;
          break;
     }
}
```

but it stops on the first one it receives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you even tried searching for a solution? There is a method which does exactly that:

> `Array.LastIndexOf` Method
>
> Returns the index of the last occurrence of a value in a one-dimensional Array or in a portion of the Array.

```
var index = Array.LastIndexOf(source, valueYoureLookingFor);
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me with one more thing? I need to check if the array contains 2 or more "1"s.

Comment: @user3476998 You can use LINQ: `source.Count(x => x == 1) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

It stops on the first one because of the break, if you remove the break, your code should do the trick.

```
for (int i = 0; i < val.Count; i++)
{
     if (val[i] == 1)
     {
          value = i + 1;
     }
}
```

Edit: beat me to it, MarcinJuraszek's solution is much better nonetheless.